# Node + mongo-native: how to find and update value in collection?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, collections, find

I have user accounts, expiring by time. Time is stored in MongoDB as a long in milliseconds. Users are identified by _id. Here's the schema:

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "506a1438be4f73c11c000002"
    },
    "email": "admin",
    "password": "admin",
    "first_name": "admin",
    "last_name": "admin",
    "country": "USA",
    "group": "admin",
    "expires": 1349129272918
}
```

To add +N days to user accounts, I use find() and then update () (dont know why, but findAndUpdate can't get previous value):

```
app.post('/users/add', function(req,res){
    addDays(req.body.id, req.body.days, function(status){
        res.send(200);
    })
});

function addDays(id, days, callback) {
    var obj_id = BSON.ObjectID.createFromHexString(id);
    db.collection("users", function(error, collection) {
        collection.find({_id: obj_id}, function(err, user) {
            var oldexp = user.expires;
            if (oldexp < new Date().getTime() ) {
                var newexp = new Date().getTime() + (86400000*days);
            } else {
                var newexp = oldexp + (86400000*days);
            }
            collection.update({_id: obj_id}, {
                $set: {
                    "expires": parseInt(newexp)
                }
            }, function(err, result) {
                callback('ok');
            });
        });
    });
}
```

To launch update days function, I use JS on frontend:

```
  $(".addDays").live("click", function(){
    var that = $(this);
    var id = that.closest('.row').find('input[name=id]').val();
    alert(id);
    $.post('/users/add', {
        "id": id,
        "days": 10
      }, function(data){
          alert(data);
      });
  });
```

Var id is a string-decoded ObejctID (like "506a1438be4f73c11c000002"), for every user it's stored in the nearest input(name="id").

**After I try to add days, even I get OK, my collection becomes damaged. Does anyone know why? Thanks!**

Comment: Can you elaborate on "my collection becomes damaged"? What actually happens to it?

Comment: since you are storing expires as a number, why not just use the $inc operator?

Comment: @IlyaRusanen would you be able to explain how your collection looks after this operation? and why you can't use $inc?

Comment: @AsyaKamsky, thanks - $inc works perfect, but unfortunatelly, it's not  extactly what I need. I need to *get* current value, determine if it's  before or after current moment, and depending on it set new value (see my code). So, automatic $inc cannot be used, though it works perfect. Damaged - means unreadable by mViewer (my admin panel for MongoDB). It says my MongoDB is corrupted after icorrect updating.

Comment: You can do a conditional update like that you just need to do two updates (but only one of them will have effect)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you say you need to make different update depending on if the current value is greater than "now" or not, why not do it with these two updates:

```
now = new Date().getTime();
db.users.update({_id:obj_id, expires:{$gte:now}, {$inc:{expires:now+{86400000*days}})
db.users.update({_id:obj_id, expires:{$lt:now}, {$set:{expires:now+86400000*days}})
```

I think this is safer than the logic you have now.

Note that the order of updates here matters to make sure only one of the two statements has effect.

Comment: Fantastic, worked like a charm! И, кажется, вы говорите по-русски, так что еще раз спасибо! :)